# Ownership of .gnupg folder causing permission denied

Tags: permissions, gpg, ownership

there are some workerNodes in which different users wants to encrpyt or decrypt certain files. for that to happen they import the required keys that they themselves are passing to. 
(Hadoop project in which are shell scripts to do so)
Now the issue is that if a particular user accesses a certain worker node it creates the .gnupg folder and the permissions are given only to that particular user. And when any other user access that particular workdernode to import and encrypt/decrypt, it says permission denied. 
The error says as follows

gpg: failed to create temporary file `locationof tempfolder/.gnupg/.#lk0xcca990.pphdpworkr546" : Permission Denied

Comment: also is it wrong to give access to that folder to all users ?

Comment: Why are different users trying to use the same private keyring?

Comment: The private keys for both users are different. but i am not sure of how gpg internally works but it is accessing the same folder again. (i am pretty naive in gpg and encryption space)